# Lualatex-dev in Texmaker

Tags: lualatex-dev

How is lualatex-dev added to texmaker dropdown list used for file compilation, also is there a guide to its use in other latex editors? I tried adding the line (lualatex-dev %.tex) to the user commands to add Lualatex-dev to texmaker compilation dropdown list but the compilation is stuck, it seems this does not work.

Comment: The easiest would be to change the lualatex setting. There is currently not much difference between both apart from the underlying engine, so it is not really  needed to have entries for both.  (I don't have texmaker so I can't help you here).

Comment: Regarding texlive 2020, is there an easy way to use (lualatex-dev) or is it still the same?

Comment: Currently there is no difference between lualatex and lualatex-dev, they use both the same engine and the same format.

Comment: Does the latex 2021 version provide any way to load the lualatex-dev?